# jqueryTe adding text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im using the Jquery text editor plugin called JqueryTE

http://jqueryte.com/

for the moment im adding some functions to it but im stuck on one right now.
Im trying to add a bit of text into the source of the textarea but it does not work.

It works with a normal textarea so its no problem there, but just this one that using jqueryTE are not working, im trying to look around in the code to find anyway to add some source into it but it does not work.

So in short, how could i add text to the textarea in a working way?

Comment: What is the question? i didn't find it..!

Comment: Edited the post, but the question is that how could i add text to the textarea ? Because it does not work with normal javascript .value = "xxx" to add any value to it.

Comment: You want to add some text into you text editor dynamically?
After it has been rendered?

Comment: Yea exacly, i wanna build a function where you click the youtube icon in the menu bar (already added the icon),then a input box to appear where you paste the youtube link (already done) then add the full html to the textarea "<iframe and so on", thats where im trapped right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual texteditor window is a div with the class "`jqte_editor`".Something like this might help u mate.

```
$("#someTextArea").parent().parent().find(".jqte_editor").html("Sample text..")
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f45zkows/)

**FYI**

**[parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**

**[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

Comment: thanks! worked perfect mate, what is the parent() function if you could explain ?

Comment: I have updated the answer.Check the links mate.It will definitely help u.If you found the answer helpful do accept it.It might help other too..

Answer (score 0):

just simply use

```
$("#someTextArea").text("Sample text");
$("#someTextArea").jqte();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f45zkows/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to update your text editor value.

```
$(".editor").jqteVal("New article!");
```

Read [this link](http://jqueryte.com/documentation#method-jqteVal)